# Site abrindo margem horizontal como resolver

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou fazendo um site que esta quase pronto e ele está abrindo margin horizontal,

Já usei

```
body{ 
    background:#CCCCCC;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

mas não funcionou, tem algum jeito para na abrir margin sem conteúdo horizontal?

Comment: Coloque o resto do código para podermos analisar.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta "tem algum jeito para na abrir margin sem conteúdo horizontal?". Revise o que você escreveu e edite sua pergunta.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, eu consegui achar o erro, tipo estava abrindo uma margin a esquerda do site com background sem na nada.

Answer (score 1):

Não percebi muito bem a pergunta mas desconfio que o teu problema será resolvido com o seguinte CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```